# Invoking program compiled using linux subsytem through python on windows

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a program I compiled in the Linux subsystem introduced in Windows 10. How can I use the python subprocess command to invoke it? By default the subprocess command seems to use the windows shell and not the linux subsytem

Here is a sample program (remember that while I am running it through a windows python anaconda interpretor), I do have linux subsytem installed

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ls', shell=False)
```

results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-cf9f6642ea11>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen('ls', shell=False)
  File "C:\Users\rt\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\rt\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: In a way similar to however you would run it from the command line. Can you do that?

Comment: @martineau, I can run it from command line using `./name_of_program`. The issue is that the python interpretor is on windows

Comment: Can you post the subprocess call? `subprocess.Popen("./name_of_program", shell=False)` should run it through Windows `CreateProcess`.

Comment: If you can run it from the command line by just giving the name of the file, you should also be able to run it via `subprocess`—which is what @tdelaney just said I believe.

Comment: I can run it from the bash that gets installed when the Linux subsytem for Windows is installed. I cannot run it from the normal windows command line as it expects .exe windows programs

Comment: @tdelaney I have updated question to include a sample subprocess call

Comment: Oh, I get it. It needs to be run in the subsystem but python doesn't know how to do that. This is a perplexing problem. I don't use it myself so I probably shouldn't have chimed in! It may be something as easy as "bash name_of_program".

Comment: @tdelaney any input is appreciated :) maybe I should just run everything on my mac but I am trying to replicate the setup on my windows machine without installing ubuntu on it

Comment: What you are doing makes sense. You are ahead of the curve here I think. You could check out the latest dev python or write a bug about it. If you don't mind trying something with a 99% chance of failure, try `subprocess._mswindows = False` and see what happens. It may end in tears.

Comment: Microsoft says `wsl.exe command` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line.

Comment: using `wsl` works! if you add it as answer, I will accept. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` uses `CreateProcess` to run programs on Windows. If you use `shell=True` it adds `cmd.exe` to the front of your command so that it is run through Windows command interpreter instead of direct execution. You can play the same game with the *Windows Subsystem for Linux*. It uses `wsl.exe` much like `cmd.exe`. So, with `shell=False` (the default) you can

```
Popen("wsl.exe " + "my_command param1 param2")
```

or

```
Popen(["wsl.exe"] + ["my_command", "param1", "param2"])
```